# Geofence Android 13

Tags: java, android, android-studio, geofencing, android-geofence

Does Geofence with broadcast receiver works on Android 13?
I found out the demo was provided by android developer official website " create a Geofence" isn't properly working. I'm receiving a notification only when I create a Geofence inside the " wanted" location - meaning the notification pops up only when I click " add Geofence" inside the location, otherwise when I enter the area the notification doesn't pop up .
Any suggestions?

Tried to create my own Geofence application with notifications and the results are the same. ( Using new version of Android 13)

Comment: Permission POST_NOTIFICATIONS?

Comment: The notification pops up when Geofence created inside the zone.